# SSD with fast and strong hardware encryption

Tags: macos, macbook, ssd, hardware-rec, disk-encryption

I'd like to storage solution which is both safe and fast. I know these two have been mutually exclusive in the past. However, is the situation still the same with modern SSD disks

- Do any SSDs support strong in fly encryption using hardware (not taxing CPU)?
- How much is penalty for enabling the encryptiong

What drives I should look into?

Bonus points if it runs in Macbooks (pros).

Comment: This sounds like a shopping recommendation, and is [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq#questions), but similar questions have been asked already: http://superuser.com/q/358122/494 and http://superuser.com/q/323681/494

Comment: Ok thanks. I was more hoping to ask "if it's possible technically" and "which kind of drives would support it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intel SSD 320 Series](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-320-series.html) offers onboard hardware encryption.  The drive uses AES-128 encryption and relies on a unique key as well as the ATA User Password to secure your data.  For more information, read the [Security Features Technology Brief](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-320-series-data-security-features-brief.html).