# How to completely erase Seagate external backup secure drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a `500GB Seagate SSHD`.

Since I want to sell this drive I wonder if there is any way to securely "erase" all of its contents so that nobody can recover them. Like overwrite erase on a regular HDD.

I tried it by erase and secure erase it with the **SeaTools software** directly by Seagate but it says `Overwrite erase - Failed`.

The drive is also connected via USB 3.0. It is not possible to connect it directly via SATA in my setup.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'd suggest you to try some [third-party secure erasing tools](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/), @C.M.! However, keep in mind that you'd need to be patient with the procedure since it could take some time for the mechanical part of the drive. It should get the hybrid back to its default out-of-the-box condition and erase all traces of your files. If you face any difficulties, it's probably best to contact the SSHD manufacturer's customer support for further assistance and specific utility recommendations. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Trying with Parted Magic was also my backup option but i hoped there was an "easy-one-click-way"... Thanks! ;)

Comment: The simplest way to securely wipe a SSHD is to use full disk encryption on the drive, then use something like DBAM, to wipe the drive.  While not a perfect solution by doing so you have effectively prevented in chance of anyone recovering the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [secure file erase on SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/290801/secure-file-erase-on-ssd)

Comment: and this one.   http://superuser.com/questions/22238/how-to-securely-delete-files-stored-on-a-ssd

Comment: I've also read these questions but in my case I have a SSHD not just a SSD...

Comment: What's the difference between an SSHD & an SSD? I remember a few years ago some mechanical hard drives had a few gigs of flash/SSD memory, used like a fast hardware disk cache for often used files, is that it? If so, it doesn't really sound like a duplicate of the SSD questions

Comment: I just purchased a new external drive and want to test it before using it. I also got "overwrite erase - failed". Any idea why this happens? Is this related to USB drives? I did "Long generic" and it passed.

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of erasure security do you need ?
If you need "only" the status: No recovery by (extended) keyboard and software attacks and without destruction of the SSD (CLEAR state), then a full format (Windows Vista and higher) is enough.
But if you need the status: No recovery by laboratory and destructive attacks (PURGE state):
No chance, you have to destroy the SSD.
-> In theory there will be the possibility to do a PURGE by firmware commands, but as you have written, that SeaTools failed, it will not be possible.
there is a limitation in the firmware and / or the integrated USB2SATA adapter to successful apply the proper commands.
In practice to use other commands or programs makes no sense and you will not get the 100% guarantee that all data are gone.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem just by formatting via Windows. I think this should be enough for now. But it's interesting how hard it is to just "wipe" all my data from an SSD...

Answer (score -1):

This technology paper "[How to ISE Your Drive](https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/docs/TP644_1_1211US_How_to_ISE_Your_Drive-FINAL.pdf)" gives step-by-step instructions on how to utilize ISE with the SeaTools for Windows utility software.

I got a seagate external drive as a bonus when I purchased my audio system, but unable to use it, because I dont know what password I have to unlock the drive, and I cannot use Windows disk manager to delete the volumes, and re-format the disk. I have tried many tools, like DiskPart, and linux commands, all failed.

Then I found the help from seagate own website, and downloaded the SeaTools for Windows, but still no idea how to use the tool. I tried fix all, which took 6 hours to finish, but still ends up no solution, square 1.

The seagate guide says, do a Advanced Tests, then press F8 when the popup window opens, then find the 32 characters PSID from the back of the drive, enter there, then, another menu Advanced Tools becomes enabled, and you can select SED Crypto Erase, whoray!!