# Can I rely on TRIM to destruct data after file deletion?

Tags: security, ssd, trim

I have a broken laptop that I want to return and I have some passwords already stored for it in the browser. I can delete the (Firefox) files that contain this data.

Can I rely on TRIM to destroy the underlying data? Or are there situations where the data will not be destroyed? If so, is there any method of forcing destruction of the data (besides SECURE ERASE)?

Comment: No; TRIM is no replacement for the using the secure erase feature of a SSD.  [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/22238/how-to-securely-delete-files-stored-on-a-ssd?rq=1)

Comment: There is a lot of text there, but I don't see this question answered explicitly. I can see some part where TRIM only seems to tag a block for garbage collection, but I would like to have a better description of this process and if it can somehow be triggered.

Comment: So you are asking how TRIM functions?  You asked if TRIM can function as a secure erase, it cannot, there isn't much else to say with regards to that.

Comment: Let me ask this another way. I (presumably) have unencrypted files on my SSD partition. Is there any way at all that I can erase them? I presume I could wipe them so they cannot be recovered without gaining to the SSD itself?

Comment: Encrypt the drive, then wipe the drive, then encrypt it or use the secure erase feature.  You can also safely take a 2-3 DBAN passes without worry even on a ssd.